# xml editing (CandyBar dashboard for icon pack)

Tags: java, android, xml, icons

I have been working on some icon packs for months & will be completed within a few days and I came across [CandyBar](https://github.com/danimahardhika/candybar-library)  dashboard.

I'm new learner for android and java. Still studying java & So not enough knowledge of programming but I read the tutorial on CandyBar's wiki page and understood about I guess 80%.

I understood how to configure that app according to my needs.
but I'm little bit confused regarding certain xml files.Tutorial didn't clearly explained which xml needs to be edited & which to be ignored & how to be edited to make my icons pasted in drawable folders to work on different launchers.

From this [xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2399426) tutorial I understood, three xmls:-

/res/xml/drawable.xml ...........to make icon appear on app to let user select icons

/res/xml/appfilter.xml..................need to add activities in it of various apps

/res/values/iconpack.xml _________(Not available in CandyBar)...... why ?

so by editing 1 & 2 xml I'm able to make my icon pack work on nova launcher and few similar launchers but not on "go launcher", so I'm confused if I'm doing something wrong.

Same xml which are in assets folder too ! :( should I edit them ?
Just want some clarification regarding xmls anybody used it ? or know about it ?

[all xml files picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9O72.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your icons, right click and right click> New Asset Vector at the top Type of resource: vocaloisa two options Clip Art and Local File (SVG, PSD) by clicking the clip art icon You can do download your own computer with SVG or PSD in case you want a standard that android requires.
You can also import a PNG vector directly into the drawable mass if you can not generate the SVG or PSG, as it is a graph of one and not an image that needs several dimensions you can choose to import only 1 size and work in your By while the default is already 24dp x 24, but when the default is already being erased, 24dp x 24, when you have some impression at some point of view you leave these dimensions, but it is recommended to use the Android icons or whatever you want stay in a more elegant standard. so the icons come in xml and you can edit them if you know how to mechanize with pure xml